# disable_with Doesn't work as intended when using render js: "window.location=some_path" in the controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I'm currently using Rails 5.2.3, simple_form and slim, and disable_with is automatically added when submitting forms in Rails.However disable_with doesn't wait for the Javascript to finish rendering and enables the submit button the moment the controller returns a 200.

I'm looking for a generic solution as I've this problem in multiple controllers.

View

```rb
 == simple_form_for some_model, remote: true do |f|
   = f.submit 'Save'
```

Controller:

```rb
def create
 # some class call and business logic
 render js: "window.location='#{path_to_redirect}'"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug, and is fixed in Rails 6 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29473